# Fastest way to check if a string is a valid number with a suffix

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, performance

I have an array of number suffixes in order of how big they are:

```
[0] = 0 - 999 ("")
[1] = 1,000 - 999,999 ("k")
[2] = 1,000,000 - 999,999,999 ("M")
[3+] = etc.
```

And I want to write a function to check if a string is a valid number with one of these suffixes at the end, and then return either a valid number with the suffix removed (`1.57k` to `1570`) or `false` if the input string can't be converted to a number.

I already have a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/7m0dk5gt/) for this, but it's messy and slow and I was unable to figure out how to improve it.

**Note:** Some of the prefixes start with another prefix, for example, T and TrD or Qa and QaD.  And I'd want to always match the full one, not just the first one found.

**Edit:** The array of possible suffixes can/will change.

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not just a link to it. Also, why do you think it is slow?

Comment: because of the regex, I've been told everywhere I ask that regex is slow and I shouldn't use it

Comment: Don't listen to them. Regex is slower than other approaches on some problems and faster on others. Whether its usage is appropriate always depends on the circumstances. Whether its slower in your particular case you only can find out by benchmarking two solutions against each other.

Comment: In your case, you can probably make the function a lot faster by not constructing `new RegExp`s from the array every time the function is called. It's a constant (given that your array never changes?), so store it as such.

Comment: the array can change, and what I thought `get` does is that it caches the regex until the array changes and then updates, so it would only create a new regex when the array is changed?

Comment: The code you've linked doesn't change the array, so how could we know that? And no, `get` doesn't cache anything or even automatically rebuilds when something changes, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: The code that changes the array was irrelevant to the question and this excluded, sorry for not mentioning that it could change.  That's my bad.  Also, I just looked it up again and you're right, so I could probably optimize it by adding `setSuffixes()` to the class that I use to change the array and also change the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking care of *"check if a string is a valid number with a suffix"*. You will just have to add your calculation function using this given result.

```js
function getSuffix(input){
 const [ suffix ] = input.match(/[^\d]+$/) || [];
 return suffix;
}

function suffixIsValid(suffix){
 if(!suffix){
  return false;
 }

 const suffixes = ["k", "M", "B", "T", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sp", "Oc", "No", "Dc", "UnD", "DuD", "TrD", "QaD", "QiD", "SeD", "SpD", "OcD", "NoD", "Vi", "UnV"];
 return suffixes.some(validSuffix => validSuffix.toLowerCase() === suffix.toLowerCase());
}

function isValidNumberWithValidSuffix(input){
 const number = parseFloat(input);
 const suffix = getSuffix(input);

 return !isNaN(number) && (!suffix || (suffix && suffixIsValid(suffix))) ? { number, suffix } : false;
}

console.log(isValidNumberWithValidSuffix(("InvalidNumber")));
console.log(isValidNumberWithValidSuffix(("153InvalidSuffix")));
console.log(isValidNumberWithValidSuffix(("153")));
console.log(isValidNumberWithValidSuffix(("15.3M")));
console.log(isValidNumberWithValidSuffix(("1.53qad")));
```

Comment: Instead of `[^\d]`, just `\D`.